# Task Scheduling and DST changes

Tags: java, events, scheduling, dst

I have this process which has to schedule events for different time zones. And this process will run at one fixed time zone(LN). I can easily load all the information from all the available data sources and convert the trigger time to local time and can get "initial delay" and schedule the events.

The problem is that I want my process to smart enough to detect DST changes occurred at any time zone and respond to it by re-scheduling the events. And this has to be done after process is up & running and events are scheduled. This process is developed in Java, any suggestions/advise please?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). I would call it the de facto standard of time calculations. It even allows you to [update the timezone data](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/tz_update.html), which frequently changes.